# ActiveRecord::Base.send :define_method affects all model instances when it shouldn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm sure this has to do with my lack of understanding of Ruby internals, but here goes:

Essentially I want to be able to set an 'attachments directory' within my assets folder by simply calling `has_attachments_folder "videos"` near the top of the model. Don't worry about what the method's purpose is, I have that part of it working. Example usage below.

### Video.rb

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attachment_assets_folder "videos"
end
```

### Email.rb

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attachment_assets_folder "attachments/email"
end
```

### activerecord_base.rb

```
def self.has_attachment_assets_folder(physical_path, arguments={})
    ActiveRecord::Base.send :define_method, :global_assets_path do |args={}|
        # Default to using the absolute system file path unless the argument
        # :asset_path => true is supplied
        p = "#{ Rails.root }/app/assets/#{ physical_path }"
        if args[:asset_path]
            p = "/assets/#{ physical_path.include?("/") ? physical_path.partition("/")[2..-1].join("/") : physical_path }"
        end
        p.squeeze!("/")
        logger.info "Defining global_assets_path...class name: #{ self.class.name }, physical_path: #{ physical_path }, p: #{ p }"
        p
    end
end
```

So essentially the method global_assets_path should return the full or relative path to the attachments directory specified by the call to `has_attachment_assets_folder`.

`has_attachment_assets_folder "videos", :asset_path => true` = `"/assets/videos"`
`has_attachment_assets_folder "attachments/email", :asset_path => true` = `"/assets/attachments/email"`

The thing is, if I use it in a regular context of a Rails app (one model being accessed at a time) it works just fine. However I'm running a major migration which requires me to use multiple models at once in the migration file. It seems that each model shares the method `global_assets_path` because the following happens:

### Example 1

```
Email.all.each do |e|
    puts e.global_assets_path(:asset_path => true) # Correct output of "/assets/attachments/email"
end
Video.all.each do |v|
    puts v.global_assets_path(:asset_path => true) # Correct output of "/assets/video"
end
```

### Example 2

```
test = Video.pluck(:category)
Email.all.each do |e|
    puts e.global_assets_path(:asset_path => true) # Correct output of "/assets/attachments/email"
end
Video.all.each do |v|
    puts v.global_assets_path(:asset_path => true) # Incorrect output of "/assets/attachments/email" because the Video model was instantiated for the first time on the 1st line.
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `define_method` on the wrong thing. This:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send :define_method, :global_assets_path
```

is sending `define_method` to `ActiveRecord::Base` so that exact `global_assets_path` method will be added to `ActiveRecord::Base`. When you say this:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attachment_assets_folder "attachments/email"
end
```

you want to add your `global_assets_path` method to `Email`, not `ActiveRecord::Base`. `self` will be `Email` inside that `has_attachment_assets_folder` call so you want to say:

```
def self.has_attachment_assets_folder(physical_path, arguments = {})
    define_method :global_assets_path do |args={}|
        ...
    end
end
```

to define `global_assets_path` on `self` (the `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass) and leave `ActiveRecord::Base` itself alone.